# Postman cannot get a Token for 3LOath on Autodesk Forge

Tags: postman, access-token, autodesk-forge

I am  trying to get a Token from Postman to access my Forge app and try out some code. I have followed the documentation but Postmen will not get a Token. After doing some research it seems there are disagreements on how the request should be formatted. 
The official ADESK documentation says use authorization code grant, but some users have said only use Implicit Grant. I have tried both but no Token has been generated. I have all the fields matching the documentation but no token generated. Anything i am missing?

[image: Screenshot of Token Request]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this as a reference on how to use Postman to get a 3 legged token and get the Authorization flow prompt https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3-legged-authentication-postman

Comment: If you look at the attached screen shot you see i am matching that, still does not work.